# Is it necessary to set a Content-Type in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-headers, content-type

Just started playing with Node.js and after seeing a few examples I see that usually the `Content-Type` is set before returning some content.

Usually something like this for HTML:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.write(html);
res.end();
```

For image:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png'});
res.write(img, 'binary');
res.end();
```

I read the [docs for .write()](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding) and it says if no header is specified "it will switch to implicit header mode and flush the implicit headers"

With some testing I found I can just write one line like so:

```
res.end(html); // or
res.end(img);
```

These both work fine.  I also tested with my local Apache server and when I viewed the headers being set when loading an image there was no `Content-Type` header set there.

Do I need to bother setting them?  What situations or bugs might arise if I don't?

Comment: Excellent question. The node.js doc here and there references an **implicit headers mode** but there's no documentation that's telling developers what it's doing for application developers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Content-Type` header is technically optional, but then you are leaving it up to the browser to essentially *guess* what type of content you are returning. Generally you should always specify a `Content-Type` if you know the type (which you probably do).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Express within your node app, then `response.send(v)` will implicitly pick a default content-type depending on the runtime type of `v`. More specifically, the behavior of `express.Response.send(v)` is as follows:

- If `v` is a string (and no content-type has already been set) then send `Content-Type: text/html`
- If `v` is a Buffer (and no content-type has already been set) then send `Content-Type: application/content-stream`
- If `v` is any other `bool/number/object` (and no content-type has already been set) then send `Content-Type: application/json`

Here's the relevant source code from Express: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/e1b45ebd050b6f06aa38cda5aaf0c21708b0c71e/lib/response.js#L141

Answer (score 0):

Implicit headers mode means using res.setHeader() rather than node figuring out the Content-Type header for you. Using res.end(html) or res.end(img) does not serve back any Content-Type, I checked with an online http analyser. Rather they work because your browser figures it out.

Comment: NodeJs doesn't set the `Content-Type` for you. There will be no such header if you don't set it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

**Of course not**, if you are playing with NodeJs. But to make a maintainable code with different modules, large and API pages you should have 'Content-Type' in your server definition.

```
const http = require('http');

const host_name = 'localhost';
const port_number = '3000';

const server = http.createServer((erq, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    // res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.end("<h1> Head Line </h1> <br> Line 2 <br> Line 3");
});

server.listen(port_number, host_name, ()=> {
    console.log(`Listening to http://${host_name}:${port_number}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer needs refinement

- Current day Security Policy will add a Header `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`
- From MDN -- Site security testers usually expect this header to be set.

Example :: if this header is set and you are opening an HTML page without Content-Type as `text\html` the page will be shown as plain text (not as Parsed HTML)

So Yes - Content-Type should be set on each type