# Using File Systems to read Html files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, filesystems

**What is the use of {'Content-Type': 'text/html'} here?**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('demofile.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);

console.log("Listening at 8080...");`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it necessary to set a Content-Type in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340066/is-it-necessary-to-set-a-content-type-in-node-js)

Comment: Please, try to do at least a very minimal research (just put the "what is content-type header?" question in the Google search box and hit enter) before asking the question. This will help you to ask better questions in the future.

Answer (score -1):

This is used for formatting.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563067(v%3Dexchg.140)

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your answer is self contained, meaning the answer needs to be here in the Answer itself. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

when you want send back data to client you can send header to that client.
`'Content-Type': 'text/html` with this piece of code client will figure out it will receive html file.
you can send back json file or html file to clinet.
`'Content-Type': 'text/html` ===> this will show ur sending html output
`'Content-Type': 'application json` ====> this will show ur sending json output